# Unable to install jenkins in mac

Tags: macos, jenkins, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to install the Homebrew throwgh following command in Terminal:

brew install jenkins-lts

but the result is: -bash: brew: command not found

what is your recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you havent got brew installed, please run the following in a terminal:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

There is further install guidance here: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation if required